# How to compute the homology group $H_q(\mathbb{R}^n-e^r)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $e^r$ be a homeomorphic copy of $I^r$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$($I=[0,1]$).How to compute the homology group $H_q(\mathbb{R}^n-e^r)$?($r,n,q$ are non-negative integers)

Comment: $\Bbb R^n\setminus e^r$, at least when $e^r$ is the standard embedding of $I^r$, will be homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Do you know Alexander Duality?

Comment: But, in the Alexander Duality, that's $S^n$.

Comment: OK!I know how to solve it. Consider $R^n$ as the complementof a point in $S^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the Mayer-Vietoris sequence in $\mathbb{S}^n -Y$ and the following result:

$``$Let $Y$ a subset of the $\mathbb{S}^n$ homeomorphic of $I^r$. Then the reduced homology groups is 
$$
\tilde{H}_j(\mathbb{S}^n -Y)=0 \quad \forall j."
$$
The subsets were used in sequence:
$$
U = \mathbb{S}^n -(Y \cup \{pto\}), \quad V \cong \mathbb{D}^n \quad \text{and} \quad U \cap V \cong \mathbb{D}^n - \{pto\}.
$$
Comments: The $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic of $\mathbb{S}^n-\{pto\}$, $\{pto\} \subset int (V)$ and $V \cap Y = \varnothing$.